# How to call ViewDidLoad method from same class by function in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

my first class is galley class and from gallery class i pass some variable and object to my image display class and In my image display class there is next image button and when i press that button all the images which are present in my image display class are need to change.

```
       MixViewController *mixVC = [[MixViewController alloc] init];
    mixVC.readOnlyMode = YES;
    mixVC.location = location;

    NSArray *tree = location.gallerySerialised;
    NSDictionary *galleryEntryTree = [tree objectAtIndex:tappedCoverIndex];
    NSArray *sliderStates = [galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"state"];
    mixVC.infotext=[galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"description"];
    mixVC.authortext=[galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"author"];
    mixVC.tappedIndex=tappedCoverIndex;

    mixVC.initialSliderStates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:0] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:1] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:2] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:3] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:4] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:5] intValue]],
                                 nil];


    mixVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:mixVC animated:YES];
```

This is my code to call mixviewcontroller . when i press the next button than i want to change the values of Sliderstates and reload the view to display new images according to slider and Index of gallery .

now i am in mix image class in that class when user click on next than i called nextGalleryview function and i want to change image but it wont work

I write this code to call self view-did-load by passing same values but it wont change anything.

Any Help is appreciated Thank you

```
   -(void)nextGalleryView
      {
     NSLog(@"tap index is %i",tappedIndex);
        [ScrollView removeFromSuperview];
    self.readOnlyMode = YES;
    self.location = location;
    NSArray *tree = location.gallerySerialised;
    NSDictionary *galleryEntryTree = [tree objectAtIndex:tappedIndex];
    NSArray *sliderStates = [galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"state"];
    self.infotext=[galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"description"];
    self.authortext=[galleryEntryTree objectForKey:@"author"];
    self.tappedIndex=tappedIndex;

    self.initialSliderStates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:0] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:1] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:2] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:3] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:4] intValue]],
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[sliderStates objectAtIndex:5] intValue]],
                                nil];
    [self viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Comment: You should never call viewDidLoad directly except when calling the superclass implementation in a subclass.

Comment: @mrueg ok any other idea to reload view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redesign your code.

If you want same code to be run from viewDidLoad and from other method, pull those codes out of viewDidLoad and put it in a method and call this method from viewDidLoad and from your method.

As calling viewDidLoad explicitly is not good.

Comment: I doubt that this will call viewDidLoad.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Dude I write another function and added few code into that and thanks to your [self.view setNeedsDisplay] i can reload my images..

Comment: So you used both the answers :)